# JSON simple not found when JAR file is in class path

Tags: java, json

Im working on a java swing project and trying to parse JSON into my project. Now I've included a simple JSON jar file in my classpath but when I try to create the json parser I keep running into errors.

the error message said is that the import is not accessible. trying to understand where im going wrong here as everything looks like it should work.

Thanks

[image: adding to library]

[image: errors highlight]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using module system, in this case you'd have to do the following:

1. Remove that json-simple jar from class path and add it into Modulepath (in the same dialog)
2. Then modify `module-info.java` file in your project, in the module definition it should contain `requires json.simple`.

Alternative solution: Remove module-info.java, then you can keep json-simple jar in the classpath.

Comment: Awesome that did it! strange when i was researching it said either or is fine, but thank you!